# Algorithm "qgis:difference" returns multiple heterogeneous outputs

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, algorithm, differences, qgsvectorlayer

I use the `qgis:difference` algorithm but it returns multi-type outputs. Sometimes it's a `QgsVectorLayer` but sometimes a `str` such as : `output_...`.

My question is : when the algorithm returns an empty result (the input is NULL so the difference too), does QGIS create an empty layer in the output that isn't readable ? Or is it a specific problem of the difference ?